# c++11 warning on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, g++, clang

I have clang 13.0.0 on my Mac. I'm trying to compile some `.cpp` files using the command

```
g++ file.cpp -o file
```

But I get this warning message:

```
file.cpp:23:26: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (const double &e : timestamp) outFile << std::setprecision(10) << e << "\n";
```

On the clang documentation is said that c++11 is supported by clang 13. On my terminal running `man clang` I find: `The default C++ language standard is gnu++14`.

Typing `g++ -v` I get:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: Using ```clang file.cpp -o file``` doesn't change the result

Comment: @MatteoBrini and `g++ --std=c++14 file.cpp -o file`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Works, but why do I have to add the first flag?

Comment: @MatteoBrini good question, you almost should ask a new question like _"Why is the default c++ standard C++11 and not C++14 on clang 13.0.0 on my MacOS even when the documentations says it's C++14?"_ Or maybe just change the question title

Comment: @Jabberwocky the fact is this: my clang version can compile c++14 scripts because of the output given by ```man clang```. The code I'm compiling says it requires at least c++11. Add the flag ```--std=c++14``` solves it but it shouldn't be necessary if my default language for ```.cpp``` files is already ```gnu++14```

Answer (score 4):

*AppleClang* defaults to c++98, whereas *llvm-clang* defaults to the later gnu++14; to access the c++11 implementation, you must add the flag, `--std=c++11` or `--std=c++14`. cf. https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-703.0.29/src/tools/clang/www/cxx_status.html

If you are expecting the gnu `g++`, it must be installed separately, because on macOS `g++` aliases to `clang`, which is the Apple fork of clang known as *AppleClang*.

If you were expecting `llvm-clang`, that also must be separately installed.  *AppleClang* 13 ≠ *llvm-clang* 13.

Comment: What do you suggest as the cleanest thing to do for compiling such files? Is there any good guide you can suggest me to know more about c++ compiling on macOS?

Comment: If you intend to compile from the command line, it is possible to use the CXXFLAGS environment variable.  It is also possible to assign the environment variable on the command line just before the compilation command.  For production builds, Xcode is very popular for macOS, whereas `meson` or `cmake` are popular modern cross-platform build scripting languages.  In these systems you can specify the language standard using configuration commands from the command line or from an external script. In the old days, you would work this into a `Makefile`; this is now automatic in `cmake` and `meson`.